# USB Formatting Problem

Tags: usb, gparted, disk-formatting

So i have an 8gb usb flash drive and when i try to create a partition in it on Disks but it says: "Error creating partition on /dev/SDB: Failed to meet partition size on device '/dev/SDB'(u disks-error-quack-error-quack, 0).Now the thing is when i go on GParted it says that my usb is 965,80 mb but its 8gb . I dont know what to do . Also when i try to format it using terminal commands nothing happens.Nothing changes . I type : "sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1" , the command doesn't give me an error but it doesn't do anything. Please i need help.  I think there is a problem and the os things its a 1gb usb or i changed something accidentally and I don't know how to fix it .

Comment: Start by showing us the screenshot from GParted, and the output of `sudo fdisk -l` when the device is connected

Comment: The usb doesnt even appear

Comment: That sounds a lot more like the USB stick has died and is broken - that's a hardware failure in the stick and not something we can fix.

Comment: But when i connected it on my phone using an OTG it worked fine .

Comment: I tested it by adding files in it plugging it out and in the computer . Nothing happened on the computer but the file was still there on my phone.

Comment: except your phone doesn't try and validate things.  Your stick might be encrypted by the phone if you're using it with OTG, in which case Linux won't recognize it.  Check with another computer - plug the stick in there.  See if it gets recognized.  If not, then your phone is lying to you about the device 'working'

Comment: So there is an app called EtchDroid on the Google Play Store and it allows you to make bootable usb using your phone.  I am going to reinstall Linux or at least try to and i will tell you what happens

Comment: I already tried it and it works.

Comment: Sooo . I was right . The something had to do with the os bc the installation booted successfully with no problems so yeah

Answer (score 0):

Try to erase the MBR of your USB disk:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
```

Comment: Yea emm . I already fixed it